# new line (\n) in php received post data

Tags: php

I post some string (like "hello \n World") to a php script then send this data to an API but the API seems not to detect \n and not make new lines and print them just as they are ("hello \n World"). this is how I do it:

```
uploadPhoto($photo->getFile(), ['caption' => $_POST['caption']]);
```

but when I do it like :

```
uploadPhoto($photo->getFile(), ['caption' => "Hello \n World"]);
```

the API detects it and shows:

Hello

World

What should I do the $_POST['caption'] part to make this work?

Comment: have you used nl2br()

Comment: Where is `$_POST['caption']` coming from? A form textfield? If I understand it right, you are writing `\n` in a form and expecting it to transform into a newline.

Comment: @sidyll I post it from android device using retrofit, I make the string("Hello \n World") and post it. there is no html form and html output.

Comment: It will be treated as a string not a newline - https://3v4l.org/PnPNL

Comment: @seravee yes but no chance, I guess that is for html output.

Comment: Hopefully your protecting from a stored XSS, my captions always contain javascript, and sometimes SQL queries. ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string probably contains the two characters, backslash and `n`. They are only interpreted as an escape sequence (which generates the newline character) by PHP when writing a string directly in code. Your input is just a sequence of characters that were received, not a PHP double-quoted string.

If you only care about newlines, you could use a simple [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$caption = str_replace('\n', "\n", $_POST['caption']);
uploadPhoto($photo->getFile(), ['caption' => $caption]);
```

Note the use of single and double quotes. The first case is similar to your input.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today
and found this function [stripcslashes](https://www.php.net/stripcslashes) could do the job.